# Show that if A⊆B -knowing that B is bounded and non-empty set- , then inf B≤ inf A≤ sup A≤ sup B

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I am currently an analysis 1 student and this is my approach to the answer to the question above, hope that you be very responsive and rectify any errors if they exist, so as, I and other members of the group can learn.
since B is a bounded set we have the following: 
**∀x∈B : inf(B)≤x≤sup(B)**
and since **A⊆B** then **∀x∈A : inf(B)≤x≤sup(B)**
as a conclusion **A** is bounded and we have the following: 
**(∃ inf(A) ∈ ℝ )(∃ sup(A) ∈ ℝ)/ ∀x∈A : inf(A)≤x≤sup(A)**
now we need to prove that **inf B≤ inf A≤ sup A≤ sup B**
and as a gateway, I chose to prove that **(inf(A),sup(A))∈B²**

Let m be the set of all minorants of set A and let M be the set of all majorants of set A:

-if **m∩B≠∅** then **inf(A)∈B** (because inf(A) is the greatest minorant so at least we have **m∩B={inf(A)}**)

-if **m∩B=∅** then **inf(A)=inf(B)**

-if **M∩B≠∅** then **sup(A)∈B** (because sup(A) is the smallest majorant so at least we have **M∩B={sup(A)}**)

-if **M∩B=∅** then **sup(A)=Sup(B)**

so, as a conclusion **(inf(A),sup(A))∈B²**
and if inf(A) and sup(A) are elements of B they verify the following:
**inf B≤ inf A≤ sup A≤ sup B**

Comment: You also need that $A$ is non-empty.

Comment: I see that all these Answers are correct and very precise but please , can the persons Who answered my question suggest any rectifations on my answer in order for it to be correct if it's not . I really want to keep the pattern that i followed so that i Never forget it in the future. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Jalal, what are you talking about? The people answering your question have done exactly what you ask! In particular, you should abandon your idea that $\inf(A)\in B$.

Comment: @TonyK so is my approach completely wrong or does it need Some corrections if yes please mention it , i also didn't say that people Who answered my question didn't do their part , They did and i greatly thank them and respect them. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need the assumption that $A$ is non-empty. For, if $A$
is empty, by convention, $\inf\emptyset=+\infty$ while $\sup\emptyset=-\infty$.
Then, we do not have $\inf A\leq\sup A$.

Suppose that $A$ is non-empty, $A\subseteq B$, and $B$ is a bounded
set.

1. $\inf(B)\leq\inf A$: Let $x\in A$ be arbitrary, then $x\in B$
   (because $A\subseteq B$). Now $\inf B$ is a lower bound for $B$,
   so $\inf B\leq x$. Since $x\in A$ is arbitrary, this shows that
   $\inf B$ is a lower bound for $A$. Therefore $\inf B$ is less than
   or equal to the greatest lower bound of $A$, i.e., $\inf B\leq\inf A$.
2. $\inf A\leq\sup A$: Since $A$ is non-empty, there exists $x_{0}\in A$.
   $\inf A$ is a lower bound for $A$ $\Rightarrow$ $\inf A\leq x_{0}$.
   $\sup A$ is an upper bound for $A$ $\Rightarrow$ $x_{0}\leq\sup A$.
   Combining, we obtain $\inf A\leq\sup A$.
3. $\sup A\leq\sup B$. Let $x\in A$ be arbitrary, then $x\in B$
   (because $A\subseteq B$). Since $\sup B$ is an upper bound for $B$,
   we have $x\leq\sup B$. Since $x\in A$ is arbitrary, we actually
   have proved that $\sup B$ is an upper bound for $A$. By definition,
   $\sup A$ is the smallest upper bound for $A$, so $\sup A\leq\sup B$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can't prove that $\inf(A)\in B$, even if $m\cap B \neq \emptyset$ (same reasoning for $\sup(A)$). Take the example : $B = \{0\} \cup (1,2)\cup \{4\}$ and $A  = (1,2)$. If $m\cap B \neq \emptyset$ you can directly conclude that $inf(B) \leq \inf(A)$.

Comment: A is not empty is given

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i had the same approoch but i thought that to achievte it it is a way to show that inf(a) and sup(a) are in set B

Comment: @Jalal, $A$ non-empty is _not_ given. All you say is that $B$ is non-empty.

Comment: I made a mistake , sorry

Answer (score 2):

Let $A \subseteq \Re$. If $\exists$ $sup(A)$ $\in$ $\Re$ and $\alpha \in \Re$ is an upper bound of $A$, then $\alpha=sup(A) \Leftarrow\Rightarrow$ $\forall$ $\epsilon > 0$ $\exists$ $x$ $\in$ $A$ such that $\alpha \ge x > \alpha - \epsilon$. The other definiton of $inf (A)$ is analogous with $\beta \le y < \beta + \epsilon$ for a lower bound of $A$. The proof of this equivalence is pretty simple.

You already have that $sup(B)$ is an upper bound of  $A$ because $A \subseteq B$.

Proof by contradiction: 
Supose that $supA > supB$ $\Rightarrow$ for $\epsilon = supA - supB > 0$, $\exists$  $x\in A$ such that $x > sup(A) - \epsilon = sup(A) - (supA - supB) = sup(B)$ $\Rightarrow$ $\exists$  $x\in A $such that $x>sup(B) $! Because that means that $sup(B)$ isn't  an upper bound of $A$, contrary to our assumption. Therefore, $sup(A) \le sup(B)$ due to tricotomy axioms of the field.

The other proof is analogous.

Comment: The first line $\alpha = \sup(A)$ if and only if ... is wrong.

For example, let $A = [0,1]$. Then $\sup(A)=1$.
Let $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$. Clearly $\alpha \neq \sup(A)$.
However, the condition on the right is satisfied.
For example, given $\epsilon >0$, we take $x=0.9 \in A$,
then $x > \alpha - \epsilon$.

Comment: If forgot the last hipotesis, I just edited it now.